# Difference between thick vs thin front suspension?

Tags: mountain-bike, suspension, full-suspension, front

I visited a bicycle shop a few days ago. I noticed two different types of bikes. One with thick front suspension and the other with thin front suspension. Bike with the thick suspension was more expensive.
Does thick suspension provide benefits or just add weight?
Is thin suspension more better than thick one?

*Thick Suspension:*

[image: thick suspension]

*Thin Suspension:*

[image: thin suspension]

*Full Images:*

[image: Full image]
[image: Full image 2]

Comment: Do note that the visible diameter is not usually the diameter of the thinnest member.  Rather, what you are seeing is a casing around a thinner rod.

Comment: OMG those 'mudguards'!

Comment: And the first one is "dual-crown"!

Comment: Do note the colour of the bare stanchions is misleading - black is slimming compared to the silver one.   Also both of these bikes look like BSOs, where quantity of material is often used to make up for a lack of structural quality.  The high spoke count front wheel is a prime example of "add more metal" over making it better.  And those brake lever angles!!

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov Tell ya what, It only costs $115. And the tires are fat too.

Comment: I still can't make choice. Which bicycle is best? The second one is also available in disk brakes.

Comment: Both of these forks are for holding the wheel in place and should not be considered as "suspension" anything. Pretty much a rigid fork with "suspension" styling.

Comment: @Klaster_1 Which bicycle do you think is best?

Comment: @BlackThunder I'd say both are equally crappy. Get whatever looks better for you and don't expect much from it.

Comment: Is this one good: https://tinyurl.com/y5zn8w92

Comment: Actually, much people don't drive in my country, so cycles are a bit cheap.

Comment: @BlackThunder Cheap does not always mean crappy, but in this case, it unfortunately is. For mountain biking, both of these bikes are equally incapable and, let me be honest, dangerous. It might not be seen at the front suspension, but look at the rear "shock": it's just a spring in both cases! no oil camera, no nothing. It will bounce uncontrollably trying to throw a rider forward. You'd be better off with a hardtail. For road riding (e.g. commuting), both of these bikes weigh excessively and have too many components to maintain. Again, a full rigid bike at the same price will be better.

Comment: The first one has radially laced wheels and disk brakes. If the brakes work at all, the wheels will self destruct when you use them.

Comment: @ojs radial lacing _can_ be used with disk brakes (both my Extralite-laced wheelsets are like that), so who knows what would happen to the bike above.

Comment: @Klaster_1 of course it can be done. You can do the math on what happens when you brake with these yourself. For what it's worth, Extralite doesn't seem to sell radial spoked disc brake wheels any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fork-leg diameter is not really how you would classify suspension forks. Or more exactly, it is a way, but not really the most relevant.

Suspension forks could be classified by how much travel they provide (different travel for different specific uses), the suspension mechanism (springs, fluid, elastomers, air, hybrid), the damping mechanism, etc.

I suspect that both those bikes were pretty cheap, both probably use spring suspension, and neither is really intended for hard off-road use. A bigger-diameter tube isn't necessarily heavier, as it can be made with thinner walls.

Comment: Fox forks are literally named and classified after stanchion diameter.

Answer (score 2):

Well they do are a little bit sturdier. Bigger diametre is harder to bend than a thin one and should requiere less material. Other thing is that the one on the red bike is a double crown, which has the benefit of being sturdier on force loads from the front of the bike.

But the most important aspect is the quality of the materials used. For example in my early days(circa 2000) I bought this "ZOOM 110 Inverted fork 20mm axle suspension with 40mm bars" which was a double crown and made out of aluminium. Thing was massive I felt like Josh Bender.

After a couple drops(like 4) the thing bent forwards and was stuck, dad wanted to kill me. My old RST sigma xl on the other hand, was WAY better with 28mm steel bars, 14mm axle and was a standard fork, thing was bomb proof for the time. This one lasted a long time.

So the most important aspect is the design and materials used. In this case both are about the same, probably the double crown is a little bit sturdier, but both are just an entry level fork and for lesiure rides you will be better of with the single crown fork. It should have the same ride quality with less weight.